# python dict append to list error(value with \)

Tags: python, list, append

I got a problem when appending a dict to list

```
    data = []
    path = "abc\cde"
    data.append({"image": path})
    print(data)
```

When I append the path to the image, the output of data is [{'image':'abc\def'}].
It contains two \ instead of one.

Comment: its just how python shows it within dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When typing text that contains slashes, use [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) to avoid having some sequences be interpreted as special characters, e.g. `"\n"` in a python string is a single character that represents a new line.

```py
>>> data = []
>>> data.append({"image": r'abc\cde'})
>>> data
[{'image': 'abc\\cde'}]
>>>
>>> data.append({"image": r'abc\nasdf'})
>>> data
[{'image': 'abc\\cde'}, {'image': 'abc\\nasdf'}]
```

When you see two slashes is because that's how python [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)-esents a string with slashes safely, it's not the actual content.

```py
>>> r'abc\cde'
'abc\\cde'
>>> r'abc\nasdf'
'abc\\nasdf'
```

In this way a text with special chars can be visualized in a compact way. If you want to see what the actual content of those strings looks like, `print` them:

```py
>>> print(r'abc\cde')
abc\cde
>>> print(r'abc\nasdf')
abc\nasdf
>>> print('abc\cde')
abc\cde
>>> print('abc\nasdf')
abc
asdf
```

Using raw strings only applies to strings you type manually, it's a method to explain python how to interpret certain characters. If the string comes from e.g. a file or a stream, the "meaning" of its char is already defined.
Regarding your question on how to concatenate a raw string (again, a raw string is a normal string) with a variable, there's no difference.

```py
>>> with_slash = r'abc\cde'
>>> wout_slash = 'asdf'
>>> with_slash + wout_slash
'abc\\cdeasdf'
>>> print(with_slash + wout_slash)
abc\cdeasdf
```

Comment: May I ask how to concatenate raw string with variable? In this program line 3, I try to use "image": r path but it is incorrect. I am saving the file path to JSON in another program, so I can't use r'abc\def' directly. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer, but I'm not sure I understood your question. Please update your question above with more details and an actual example, and what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

The additional backslash is Python escaping the single backslash. The actual value of your `path` string is unchanged, as you can see when the value of `data[0]['image']` is printed.

```
data = []
path = 'abc\cde'
data.append({"image": path})

# output: abc\cde
print(data[0]['image'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character. It allows you to use special symbols, for example a new line `\n` or tab `\t`. If you want a string to contain a literal `\`, make sure that you put another `\` before it.

In your case, Python understands that you meant `"abc\\cde"` even though you did not escape `\`. If you had `abc\nde`, the result would be `abc<line_break>de`.

```py
>>> a = "abc\\cde"
>>> a
'abc\\cde'
>>> list(a)
['a', 'b', 'c', '\\', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

As you see, even though it looks like a double backslash, it is just one `\` character.

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp

Comment: Note that the behavior of interpreting unrecognized escapes as a backslash followed by the character in string literals is deprecated since 3.6 (it causes too many problems when `'abc\cde'` works and people get used to using it, then get bitten by the seemingly equivalent usage `'klm\nop'`), so if you have warnings enabled, that literal would alert. It will eventually become a `SyntaxWarning`, then `SyntaxError`.